# Firebase Value event listener doesnt work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got Value event listener working but once I've removed listeners in `onPause` and `onStop` even after I start the application afer closing it , the value event listener is not working.

```
public class Payment extends AppCompatActivity implements IppoPayListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);

       
     
        proceedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    placeOrder();
            }
        });
    }


    
    private void placeOrder() {

        cartDbRef=FirebaseInit.getDatabase().getReference().child("USERS/"+phonenumber+"/cart");
        cartlistener=cartDbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()){
                    String segment=dataSnapshot.child("segment").getValue(String.class);
                    int quantity=dataSnapshot.child("userquantity").getValue(Integer.class);
                    
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
       
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (cartDbRef != null && cartlistener!=null) {
            cartDbRef.removeEventListener(cartlistener);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        super.onStop();
        if (cartDbRef != null && cartlistener != null) {
            cartDbRef.removeEventListener(cartlistener);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

When `placeOrder()` is called on click  , the code following the cartDbRef is not even executed , but it works when i did not remove the cartListener in `onPause` and `onResume`

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo I made an edit following your suggestion, kindly check. Thanks

Comment: Is your onDataChange even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo No. It didn't

Comment: Side note: `super.onStop()` should be removed from the `onPause()`

Comment: @Zain android studio marks it in red is that alright?

Comment: I think it warns you that shouldn't be called here.. But I thin the app will work normally if leave it; the bottom is it should be called within `onStop()` callback not in `onPause()` .. Leave `super.onPause()` like it is in `onPause()`

Comment: Most likely you don't have internet connection on the device, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo  it does have internet.

Comment: Is your onCancelled triggered? If yes, how do you check that? I recommend you stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo I basically do the log.d thing I checked it out onCancelled is not triggered. And log doesn't print anything at alll ....thats why I had to assume it had skipped that whole ValueEventListener part

Comment: The `onPause` and `onStop` should not be triggered immediately when you click the button. Can you place breakpoints on/in all these methods, run in a debugger, and then update your question showing the calls that happened and in what order? Alternatively, place `Log.d()` statements in each method and block, and show the updated code and its output in your question. That way we're all looking at the same code and output, instead of you describing your findings to us in a more lossy way.

Comment: If none of the methods is triggered, then no internet connection is present on the user device.